# Least-impact solution to binary references in VCS

Tags: teamcity

We are using TeamCity 2017.1 and have been using it for years with great joy. A long time ago, someone decided that all third-party binaires should be put into Subversion (our VCS of choice).

This has worked fine, but over time this repos has grown quite large, and combined with our being better and better at using TeamCity, we now have dozens of build configurations which *all* uses third-party binaries.

Our third-party folder is called Department and is around 2.6 GB in size. As such this is not so bad, but remember that this folder is used by pretty much *every single project on the build server*!

Now, I will agree with everyone that says that we should use Nugets, network shares etc., and that would work great with new projects. However, we have a lot of history and we cannot begin to change every single solution and branch.

A co-worker came up with the idea, that IF we made a single build project that in reality did nothing but keep a single folder updated with our Department stuff. Then we just need to find a way to reference this, without have to change all our projects and solutions.

My initial though is using Snapshot dependencies and then create a symbolic link as the first build step and remove it as the last, in order to achieve the same relative levels.

But is there a better way? What do other people do?

And keep in mind, that replacing with nugets or something else is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me follow the idea of your colleague and improve it. There would be a build configuration that monitors the Subversion repository and copies packages to a network share. That network share will be used by development teams as nuget repository. Projects that will convert their dependencies from Binary reference to nuget reference will enjoy faster build. When all the teams will use nuget repositories you may kill that Subversion.

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, it is not plausible for the immediate future. 
This would be a long-term goal however.